# Add Previous/Next Buttons to CPT Single Pages Only

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I'm working with a site that is displaying a portfolio CPT on the home page in a "Grid Loop." On the single pages, i'd like to add Previous & Next Item buttons. I thus added this code:

```
function custom_post_navigation()
{
?>
    <div class="prev_next">
        <div class="nav_left">
            <span class="prev"><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous Item</span>'); ?>
         </div class="nav_right">
        <div>
            <span class="next"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Item</span>'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}

add_action('genesis_before_post_title', 'custom_post_navigation');
```

On the site [Safety Warehouse](http://safetywarehouse.net) It now displays the links properly on the single item pages, but It is also displaying Previous and Next buttons on the home page as well.

How can I remove them from the home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Genesis, but I assume you can wrap the output of your function in a check if `is_single()`:

```
function custom_post_navigation()
{
    if( is_single() )
    {
        // output next/prev links
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks a ton! I didn't realize you could use the `is_single()` conditional on CPTs.